# Redux Form Async validation infinite recursion

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I use redux-form@7.0.4 in my application. There is some fields where i need to define a validate function dynamically.
Note that I need **id** and **slice** to look for the correct field in values

```
<Field
    component={SemanticFormField}
    as={Input}
    placeholder="From"
    name={"participation-card-" + id + "-slice-" + slice + "-min"}
    validate={[number]}
    />
<Field
    component={SemanticFormField}
    as={Input}
    placeholder="to"
    name={"participation-card-" + id + "-slice-" + slice + "-max"}
    validate={[number, validateMaxSlice(slice, id)]}
    />
```

When i define validateMaxSlice like this

```
const validateMaxSlice = (slice, id) => (value, values) => {
    const min = values["participation-card-" + id + "-slice-" + slice + "-min"];
    return min >= value ? "Invalid slice" : undefined;
};
```

Or inline like this

```
validate={[number, (value, values) => {
const min = values["participation-card-" + id + "-slice-" + slice + "-min"];
    return min >= value ? "Invalid slice" : undefined;}]
```

The application goes in an infinite loop the moment it renders the component.

The question is why and how to fix it ?

**Edit:**

Thank you for your help ! Here is how I implement it

Container part:

```
createSlice() {
    const id = uuidv4();
    return {
        id,
        validators: (value, values) => {
            const min = values["participation-card-" + this.props.id + "-slice-" + id + "-min"];
            return valSup(value, "Tranche incorrecte")(min);
        },
    };
}

addParticipationSlice() {
    let participationSlices = this.state.participationSlices;

    participationSlices.push(this.createSlice());

    this.setState({
        participationSlices,
    });
}
```

Scene part:

```
<Field
    component={SemanticFormField}
    as={Input}
    name={"participation-card-" + id + "-slice-" + slice.id + "-max"}
    size="mini"
    width={7}
    validate={[number, slice.validators]}
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are creating validators on the fly, it create a new validator instance every time it redraw.

On the first redraw, React try to validate the value, then redraw to update the view. This, in turn, create a new validate function and change the related props value.

As you change the props to the component, react will trigger a re-render of the Field. Thus causing it to revalidate again, causing again a re-render.

One way to correct it is to generate one and only one version of each callback, reusing functions instances when appropriate.

You can for example store a this.validators associative array then change your function generator to something like this:

```
validateMaxSlice(slice, id) => {
     if (!this.validators[`${slice}-${id}`]) {
          this.validators[`${slice}-${id}`] = (value, values) => { ...Actual validation code... }
     }
     return this.validators[`${slice}-${id}`]
}
```

This way, validators are created on the fly but reused where they need to be.